# Android - LongPress Vibrates when using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

When I long press anywhere inside my Apps which I develop using PhoneGap, they vibrate.

This only occurs on a real device running Android. It doesn't happen in the simulator.

How can I stop that? Could it be stopped from within Eclipse, or it's a Javascript issue?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: What devices have you been testing on? Are you using the vibrate API at all anywhere in your app? It happens when you longpress anywhere, like an empty div or background picture? Or does it only happen when you longpress on a link or something? (eg, can you detect any pattern?)

Comment: @MBillau no, it is happening when I click anywhere inside the body tag. Any empty area

Comment: Have you been able to test on multiple devices or only one? I've never heard of this before and am wondering if maybe it's some strange device idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @MBillau yes I tried multiple devices. It's strange I know.

Comment: @MBillau I have events for OnTouchStart and OnTouchMove, do you think they cause vibration? I have those events for the sliding menu inside my App.

Comment: Yeah it's super weird... Those events might cause vibration, you could try removing them and see. I'd start removing bits of your app piece by piece until the problem goes away and then you can figure out what the problem is. Are you using any other js scripts or frameworks, like jquery mobile or something?

Comment: Also, are you using the Vibration API at all? Maybe some function name got clobbered and you are accidentally calling vibrate?